# Downside to multiple instances of NSNotifcationCenter in cocoa touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

I'm looking into implementing the observer design pattern in cocoa touch, and have discovered that Apple has the cool NSNotificationCenter object that seems like it'll do exactly what I'm looking for. However, most of the tutorials I've seen for this have only one or two instances of an NSNotificationCenter running.

Because of the lack of tutorials using this practice, I'm wondering: Is there any downside to having an NSNotificationCenter instance on each model I want observed? (in my specific case it'll be about 16 models). Or is there a way for to tell a view to observe only a specific model, using one global instance of an NSNotificationCenter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'object' parameter of the NSNotificationCenter methods to get this effect without allocating one per object.

Comment: So for each observer I have to specifically check if `object == self.model` or something of that nature? Is that common practice?

Comment: No, when you register as an observer, you include the object as one of the registration parameters. The notification center will only deliver matching notifications then.

Comment: BINGO. Didn't see that anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Is this generally a better practice than having coupled classes and using forward declaration?

Comment: Merely using notifications instead of method calls doesn't really reduce coupling, it just makes the coupling look less direct. Notifications are primarily useful in 1:N notifier:observer situations.

Comment: I just feel weird about using `object.view = self, self.object=object`. But I guess in this case when it's one to one it is the same as using a notification center.

Comment: Yup. Remember to make one edge in the cycle weak, or manually break the cycle, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the notification center you are supposed to use the get default notification center. I think it looks like this

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I was wondering if there's any reason why there can't be more.

Comment: You can certainly allocate more notification centers if you want. The default is just that: a default, not the only option.

Comment: You can but you will take a performance hit, so it is not recommended

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: read this it states "Each running Cocoa program has a default notification center. You typically don’t create your own."

Comment: There we go. So the performance hit from having multiple instances outweighs the performance hit of running through all the views that are listening to all of the models whenever there is an event triggered? I was just thinking it may also be a performance hit if only one model triggered an event and it informed every single view about it.

Comment: Guessing about performance is rarely productive. That said, posting notifications with no object to filter them down is very likely to be more expensive in cpu than creating additional notification centers, but *might* use less ram.